# How can I do sorting on multiple columns in WebGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I am using `WebGrid` in my ASP.NET MVC 3 (C#) application. I want to do sorting on multiple columns(like we can do in tablesorter).

Is it possible in `WebGrid`? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score -1):

The WebGrid Helper provides sorting by default.

So, you'd get sorting and paging by default when you write a simple instantiation like below:

```
var myGrid = new WebGrid(Model);
myGrid.GetHtml();
```

Quoted from a dead link:

> Out of the box, the WebGrid provides these functions by doing Get requests and passing in a few values over the query string.  The WebGrid will see these values in the new request, and adjust the output accordingly.  This means that the WebGrid expects the entire set of data in each view in order to generate the paging properly.

This means  that you would have performance issues for larger datasets as you would need to pull all of it into memory at once for the Helper to compute paging and sorting metrics correctly.

Comment: Details linked to empty page

Comment: Thanks @Lucian for pointing that out. Just updated with details to make the answer less dependent on the link.